# There’s an pulsing feeling when pedaling

Tags: bottom-bracket

I sometimes feel what I can only describe as a pulse when pedaling my Boardman Comp road bike. It is intermittent and is not accompanied by any noises. I suspect it's the bottom bracket but I'm not certain. Any suggestions of what it could be?

Comment: A pulse of extra resistance? Does it occur at the same point of crank rotation?

Comment: Also: once per revolution of the cranks?

Comment: Interesting problem; but we need more information to help you.  Please edit your question with the additional details requested.

Comment: When you coast, does the pulse stop/change ?  When the pulse is there, is it 1:1 with crank rotations or is it 3-4 times faster and in sync with wheel rotations ?

Comment: Did you change anything in the days leading up to when you first felt the pulse ?

Comment: Can you make the pulse appear or disappear by doing anything?  Backpedalling or pushing really hard perhaps.

Comment: If you suspend the bike in a workstand or from some ropes (so the rear wheel is off the ground)  can you make the pulse appear by gently hand-pedalling the cranks ?

Comment: Check the spoke tension on your wheels. I've had something similar were the spokes become loose and the wheel flexes when the pedal stroke and wheel position align just right.

Comment: @rich please add further information as requested.  Without that info, everything is just a guess or a stab in the dark.

Comment: You need to describe the problem better.  There are many different scenarios that might be referred to as "pulsing".

Comment: This was never clarified, and the asker hasn't been on the site since the day they asked. Voting to close as unclear: this question is never going to be answerable.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see your chainwheel is running true, spin the cranks & use a simple pointer like a pencil held on the frame to check, watch your fingers doing this ! if it is a little bit eccentric the chain will tighten & loosen with each rotation of the cranks giving the sort of pulsation when pedalling A worn chainwheel, rear sprockets & stretched chain won't help either.
Regards,
Brunka.

PS Oppppps, Didn't really fully read question, this  will only apply for single speed / fixie type setup, if U have rear shifter/ mech won't have any real effect, eg Shimano Bio Ace eccentric chainwheels from years ago, fitted them to my road race bike, they were distinctly eccentric. Regards, Brunka.